# How to upload a face image to IVMS without overwriting the other saved images

Tags: image, testing, import, camera, software-distribution

I tried to upload a single face image to IVMS but it overwritten all the other images saved in the software. Is there any safe way I can do this without actually scanning the user's face but only  through importing an image?

I followed this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_JgxC9ph2s

which cause the overwriting on other images.